# Calculate the Mean earnings of a person

Tags: arithmetic, mean-square-error

There are $12$ employees who earn $\$750$ collectively. I need to calculate the mean salary earned by a single employee.

My workings so far: I tried to divide $750 / 12$, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: You tagged it as mean square error (MSE). Are you using 'mean' to say 'average'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **definition** of "mean" salary is total salary divided by number of contributors. You've done precisely the right thing.